# How safe are sail planes?

Tags: safety, glider, sailplane

I think sailplanes have to be pretty safe. Because if it falls it will gain speed, which will be converted to lift.

So unless you do something stupid sailplanes can't just fall out of air. Am I right?

Comment: [Close with lots of relevant info](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/51566/are-there-any-data-on-the-safety-rate-of-gliders-vs-single-engine-ga-aircraft) also some [good info here](https://www.bea.aero/etudes/glideraccidents19992001a/glideraccidents19992001a.htm)

Comment: The same is true of any powered airplane.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I'm not sure what answer you're looking for: how safe is flying a glider compared to what? To flying a powered aircraft? Driving a car? Staying at home all day? Obviously some activities are inherently riskier than others, but risk and safety are usually relative.

Comment: I've never heard of an engine failure in a non-motorized sailplane, so that's one less thing that can go wrong! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they can fall out of the sky if you mishandle them like any other airplane.  They just happen to be missing an engine.

What makes them safe is low landing speeds and the ability for an experienced pilot to place it on the ground with extreme precision, with a huge choice of descent angles.  If you are 1000 feet in the air, you have the option of landing almost under your nose using your dive brakes, or gliding 6-8 miles ahead, or anywhere in between.

As long as you have land-able terrain within gliding distance, and avoid stalling and spinning close to the ground (like any other aircraft), a glider is a low-stress, low risk type of aircraft. Serious cross country pilots "land out" in farm fields or outlying grass airports from time to time when they get caught low and away from the home field.  It's part of the sport.